# Logging static methods with log4J

Tags: java, log4j

In each class I have logger that is used for logging:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
}
```

But what to do when I need to log static methods? `log` is not static variable?

Comment: add static the the log definition ?

Comment: The only reason `log` is not a static variable is because you didn't make it one. Now you're asking us why you chose to make it non-static. We don't know why you did it, but the common style is to make it `public/private final static`

Comment: BTW, why your logger is public? If you are planning to share it with other classes - it's bad idea. Otherwise make it private.

Answer (score 20):

Make your logger static:

```
public class Myclass
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Myclass.class);
}
```

Comment: So, is there any advantages of using not static logger variable against static? It looks for me it is always better to use static one.

Comment: @vico, in fact - yes. The only disadvantage of using static loggers is that you may forget to change the name of class while copy-pasting logger to the new class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `static` keyword in the variable declaration.

**For example:**

```
public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Almost, but you can't use `this.getClass()` in a static context - use `ClassName.class` instead as Eugene highlights above

Answer (score 0):

I came up with probably the best way to do this ever... a coworker got me most of the way there with `MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass()` which grabs the class even in a static context

So this is how I used it:

```
/**
 * Simple static logging interface by David Lerner on 12/23/16.
 */
public interface Logging {
     Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
}
```

and then you simply implement your interface

```
public class test implements Logging {
    @Test
    public void newTest() {
        LOG.error("This is an error");
    }
}
```